# MS Word : How can I force a paragraph to stick with previous paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I am often writing bulleted lists in word documents. They are always preceded by an introductory paragraph with a colon at the end of it. I would like to force the list to stick with the previous paragraph and I would like it to be automatic throughout the document 'cause I've got a lot of them.

Exemple:

`Here is a list of important points:
- First point;
- Second point;
- Last point.`

There should never be a page break between those lines. I can easily force the bulleted points to stay together ('keep with next' option, with a specific style for bulleted points), but I don't know how to tell them to stay with the previous paragraph (Normal style).

Is there a way to achieve this without using a macro ?

Thanks,
Mathieu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark the previous paragraph - the one that you want the bulleted points to be associated with - as ***Keep with next*** in the Paragraph formatting. On your ribbon, click on the little icon in the lower-right corner of the paragraph section, then click on the tab marked ***Line and Page Breaks***, and turn on the *KWN* check box.

(You can always create a new style for "Bullet Point Headers", based on the normal paragraph style, and just add "keep with next" to the style as above, then apply the new style to the appropriate paragraphs.)

Comment: Thank for answer. Not exactly what I was looking for, but it sounds like an acceptable workaround 'til MS implements a 'keep with previous' option.

Comment: Functionally, I don't see a difference between the two; it's just a question of _which_ paragraph gets the format.

Comment: It means that you have to create and apply 2 specific styles when using a bulleted list instead of one with a hypothetical 'keep with previous' option.

Comment: Not necessarily; there's an option in a style definition for the style to be applied to the next paragraph - so if you set the bullet point header style's ***Style for following paragraph*** to the actual bulleted list style, all you do is set the style once at the header, and the next style will automatically be assumed and applied.

Comment: I like that, didn't think of using this option that way. Thanks!
I sometimes add a paragraph between the "Bullet Point Header" paragraph and the "Bulleted list" paragraph. That new paragraph then should become the "Bullet Point Header" instead of the previous one, which should then be reset to "Normal". A bit more manipulations, but not really annoying.

Comment: One caveat: The "Next paragraph" style is only applied _before_ you type the next paragraph. If you type the text and then go back and apply, you'll have to apply the styles manually.

Comment: Yeah I know, I was just pointing the limits of the method and the fact that I can live with them. Anyway, thank you for your time and help

Comment: I absolutely cannot understand why Microsoft removed that feature 'keep with previous' at all. No, it is not the same like 'keep with next', and it existed in ancient versions of the program.

Answer (score 2):

"keep with previous" and "keep with next" is not the same. Presuming that both paragraphs have a considerable length, "keep with previous" would hold the second paragraph together linked to the first, allowing the first to be normally treated and broken in a normal way at a page-break (that would be nice for special concluding lines, which should stick to the previous paragraph to which they belong to).
"Keep with next" makes the first paragraph stick together linked to the second and avoiding page-breaks, while the second one is treated as normal an broken in a normal way at the next page-break (that's for headlines).
there would be a third option possible, also not available in word: like "keep both together" which would be no page-break at the paragraph-break between both, but two lines before or two lines after the paragraph-break.
the forth possibility like "hold both as a whole together" with no page-break in both paragraphs is easily achieved by marking both paragraphs as "hold paragraph together" and the first one as "keep with next".

Answer (score 0):

Keep with previous would be a good feature when composing a test with multiple choice answers. In this case the question is numbered and has a paragraph style. The multiple choice answers have letter designations and a paragraph style. What I don't want are the answers to a question to be split across a page break -for example choices a and b on one page while answers c and d flowed to the next page. "keep lines together" won't work because the multiple choice answers are each a paragraph. "Keep with next" works for the question paragraph style, it will stick with the first answer. "Keep with next" won't work for the answers because if all the answers have the same format, then one ends up with all questions and answers all stuck together.  If the mulitple choice answers can be formatted as stick with previous while the questions are stick with next, the answers all stick with the respective question -no splitting across page breaks. The goal is to apply paragraph style so when making future changes, a bunch of manual page breaks aren't needed. Word does not have this feature.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).